# Why do these two methods of calculating final speed of a xenon drive engine yield different results?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

The question is about a xenon ion drive. The ion drive ejects xenon at some speed, which propels the spacecraft forwards. The parameters given in the question are:

- Mass of xenon ion: $2.2 \times 10^{-25} kg$
- Total mass of xenon used: $74 kg$
- Final speed of the spacecraft: $4.3 km/s$
- Speed at which xenon is ejected from the spacecraft: $43 km/s$
- Time for which the xenon drive is operational: 678 days
- Force applied on the spacecraft by the xenon drive: $0.12 N$

Q: What is the mass of the spacecraft?

**Method 1**: apply conservation of momentum. $74kg * 4300m/s = m * 43000m/s$, so $m = 740 kg$.

**Method 2**: The impulse is equal to the force multiplied by the time the force is applied, which is equal to the change in momentum. Or, $0.12N * 678 days = m * 4300 m/s$. This yields a $m$ of $1634 kg$.

Method 2 clearly makes an approximation that the mass of the spacecraft is constant when it shouldn't be (since it is constantly decreasing as xenon is ejected). However, the discrepancy with method 1 is huge. Where is the discrepancy coming from?

If I had to guess, it would be that method 1 is incorrect because the speed of the xenon ejected relative to the ground changes. For example when the spacecraft is moving at $4 km/s$, then the speed of the xenon relative to the spacecraft is still $43 km/s$, but relative to the ground it is only $39 km/s$, and naive conservation of momentum fails. But if this is indeed the cause of the discrepancy, then I have a different problem, because the answer key says method 1 is correct ...